# How to make image appear based on overflow status

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a div area that contains pagination, but for mobile devices to access the later pages the horizontal scrollbars do not show and the visitor has to use their finger.

I'm looking for a pretty simple solution, so I thought if I can detect if overflow has occurred a little image suggesting scroll with finger should be made visible.

Is this possible and does anyone have an example of how to write this?

Comment: This wouldn't be possible with CSS alone. You'd need to use JavaScript to detect whether the element is scrollable and proceed from there.

Comment: Does anyone have a starting point, a snippet of code I could begin with?